# Cannot Load Temp CSV file into MySQL Database

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I am trying to insert a CSV file uploaded client side into my MySQL database, however it fails each time; the MySQL table still appears empty I am fairly new to PHP/MySQL so any advice would be great!

HTML

```
<input type="file" name="file" id="file">
```

JavaScript

```
function Upload_Text()
{               
var formData = new FormData();
var file = document.getElementById("file").files[0];
formData = new FormData();
var xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
            {
                if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
                {
                    var result = xmlhttp.responseText;
                    alert(result);

                }
            }
var url = "Upload_Text.php";
formData.append("thefile", file);
xmlhttp.open('POST', url, true);
xmlhttp.send(formData);
}
```

PHP

```
<?php
$file = $_FILES['thefile']['tmp_name'];
$link = new mysqli('address', 'usr', 'pwd', 'db');
if (mysqli_connect_error()) { echo "0"; die();}
    $statement = $link->prepare("LOAD DATA INFILE ? INTO TABLE Groups FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','  LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';");
    $statement->bind_param('s', $file); 
    $statement->execute(); 
?>
```

File looks like this:

```
jakec,8
jim,5
debby,4
emily,8
terrence,2
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: Very basic question: what error do you get?

Comment: Does your form contain `enctype='multipart/form-data'` and the input name is indeed called `thefile`?

Comment: And this `$file = $_FILES['thefile']['tmp_name'];` should probably be `$file = $_FILES['thefile']['name'];` and use `var_dump();` to see if it's set or not.

Comment: Rename `name="file"` to `name="thefile"` => `$file = $_FILES['thefile']['tmp_name'];` which is the main problem. `<input type="file" name="thefile" id="file">` the `name` doesn't match. Try it out.

Comment: The file is set, I am able to read it and echo its contents line by line with $fh = fopen($file, 'r');
$theData = fread($fh, filesize($file));
fclose($fh);
echo $theData;

Comment: Consult my answer below. @JakeCallahan - it outlines the main issue.

Answer (score 0):

Changed my approach and was able to get it working with the following:

```
<?php
$connect = mysql_connect('address', 'usr', 'pwd', 'db'); 
$handle = fopen($file,"r");
do {
    if ($data[0]) { 
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO Students (NetID, GroupID) VALUES 
            ( 
                '".addslashes($data[0])."', 
                '".addslashes($data[1])."'
            ) 
        "); 
    } 
} while ($data = fgetcsv($handle,1000,",","'")); 
?>
```

Though I realize this is depreciated with php 5.5.0 so I will have to inevitably change it

Comment: Am glad you found a solution. I toyed with the idea and found out that `bind_param` could not be applied in using your original code. I myself couldn't load a file using `LOAD DATA INFILE`, maybe my host isn't letting me.